# php - converting swithch to .csv file read method

Tags: php, csv, switch-statement

Can someone please point me in the correct direction to convert my switch code from currently being listed like below to being drawn from a CSV file instead:

```
    $video = (isset($_GET['video']) ? $_GET['video'] : null);

if($video) {
    switch($video) {
        case "apple":
                    $Heading ='Apple Heading';
            $Videonum ='1';
            $Content ='<h2>Apple Sub Heading</h2>
                               <p>Apple content</p>';
            $SideContent ='Apple side content';
break;
```

I will end up with lots of cases and it'll be easier to manage from a .csv file - thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a two-dimensional array with the identifier ('apple', …) as the key for the inner arrays. By parsing a CSV-file you will get an array with multiple rows, but you need to search for the row, that contains the required data. Maybe you also can save PHP files containing the necessary data-arrays or even use a database (which is probably most common for such cases).

Target arrays as I would use it:

```
$data = array(
    'apple' => array(
        'heading' => 'Apple Heading',
        'video_num' => 1,
        'content' => '<h2>Apple Sub Heading</h2>
                      <p>Apple content</p>',
        'side_content' => 'Apple side content',
    ),
    /* more manufacturer sub-arrays */
);
```

In this first case you could access the whole data by just reading from the array:

```
if( !empty( $_GET['video'] ) && isset( $data[$_GET['video']] ) )
{
    var_dump(
        $data[$_GET['video']]['heading'],
        $data[$_GET['video']]['content']
    );
}
else
{
    echo '<p class="error">No video specified or "' . $_GET['video'] . '" is not available.</p>';
}
```

FYI; Array as retrieved from a CSV-file:

```
$data = array(
    1 => array(
        'manufacturer' => 'Apple',
        'heading' => 'Apple Heading',
        'video_num' => 1,
        'content' => '<h2>Apple Sub Heading</h2>
                      <p>Apple content</p>',
        'side_content' => 'Apple side content',
    ),
    /* more rows */
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure the advantages of your offer over the previous - can you explain to a noobie further please?

Also at the moment to reference the switch info I'm using echos like 

<?php echo $Videonum; ?>

how would I now reference the info - is it the same way? sorry for my utter lack of php knowledge

Comment: If this answer isn't self explanatory enough, I don't know how to express it in a simpler way. You know that this is a programmer forum? For example `<?php echo $Videonum; ?>` would become `<?php echo $data[$_GET['video']]['video_num']; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Read your csv file

```
$data = array();
$fp = fopen('manufacturer.csv', 'r');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line = explode(';',fgets($fp));
    $data[$line[0]]['heading'] = $line[1];
    $data[$line[0]]['video'] = $line[2];
    $data[$line[0]]['content'] = $line[3];
    $data[$line[0]]['side'] = $line[4];
}
fclose($fp);
```

Your csv looks like

```
apple;Apple Heading;1;<h2>Apple Sub Heading</h2><p>Apple content</p>;Apple side content
microsoft;MS Heading;1;<h2>MS Sub Heading</h2><p>MS content</p>;MS side content
...
```

Then acces your content with the manufacturer name

```
if(isset($data[$_GET['video']] && !empty($_GET['video']))){
    $Heading = $data[$_GET['video']]['heading'];
    $Videonum = $data[$_GET['video']]['video'];
    $Content = $data[$_GET['video']]['content'];
    $SideContent = $data[$_GET['video']]['side'];
}
```

Comment: Hey mate sorry for my lack of knowledge - I'm confused which reply is better now?

Comment: I answer your question by using au csv file, but the result is the same.

Comment: I tried the above however I modified the line:

if(isset($data[$_GET['video']]) && !empty($_GET['video'])){

to get it working.

I've been told I should use this method instead http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php ? however not sure how to impliement it.

With your code I'm getting no error messages but its not drawing the content.

Comment: `fgetcsv` should works just fine. And in did you have to echo/print the content. But I thinking you already put in HTML code, table for exemple.

Comment: No need to use `isset()` when using `empty()`, because the latter also checks for initialization too…